# Eventbrite registration on behalf of others

Tags: eventbrite

Is there any way for somebody to be registered for an event in Eventbrite by somebody else? I'm thinking of a scenario where an employer wants to register a employees for training, or a conference.

If so, could you please tell me if this is possible via the web, via the developer API, or both?

I've gone through the documentation, forums and stackoverflow and I can't find any mention of it. I'm assuming it isn't possible as you need to put in an email address, then all correspondences are sent to this email address.

I'd post this on the Eventbrite forum but there seem to be an awful lot of unanswered questions there.

Comment: I'm curious though - wouldn't you want people to register themselves so that they are indeed sincerely  going?

Comment: @coffee - ideally yes, but I'm looking at building something where one of the requirements is for an employer to register multiple employees for mandatory training.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, on the page where you edit the order form, you can require information for both the ticket purchaser and the attendee. To do this, select the radio button labeled "Each Attendee" under the heading "Attendee Information: Collection Type."